# average age of different countries

Tags: sql

I have to perform a query in which I have to show average age of all countries. I have many countries in my database, and all of them have at least two or three entries. I want to find the average age of all countries.

Comment: Define "average age of all countries" more clearly. Add the name and version of your RDBMS and what you have tired, please.

Comment: Can you show your database schema with some sample data, and a sample of what you expect the query to return?

Comment: There is a difference between the average of ALL countries and the average age of EACH country. The first is one number, the latter is 2+ numbers (as many numbers as there are countries). Which do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL should look something like this, but it's hard to say for sure without knowing your schema.

If you want the average country age, irrespective of the number of times the countries appear in your table, it would be something like:

```
SELECT AVG(age) AS averageAge
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT country, age
   FROM countries
);
```

If you want a weighted average based on whatever table you are pulling from it will be something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(age) AS averageAge
FROM countries;
```

Comment: If you get the distinct country and age, how is that an average?I think this answer is going from bad to worse.  Now you're not even showing the country that has the age.

Comment: @paqogomez It will depend on what kind of average he's looking for. The "average age of all countries" would be found by taking one age from each country and averaging it. If he wants an average that is based on the weighting of the countries in the table, that would be different.

Comment: Fair point, this would accomplish that.

Comment: You should probably clarify in your text thats what you're demonstrating, just as @tohava is getting the average country age for each country.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select country,avg(age) from t group by country
```

Comment: He says that each country is listed in the table more than once.

Comment: I am assuming each country has the same id. Otherwise he didnt provide enough info.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, won't `AVG(age)` be equivalent to `age` if you group by country? Each grouped row would group X number of original rows, each having the same country age. The average of X instances of Y is just Y.

Comment: Who says all country instances have the same age?

Comment: The way he worded the question, I assumed an `age` is a property of a `country`. If `age` is the age of something else, like a person, then yes, it could vary, and your query would find the average age by country. But I'm not sure that's what he means.